# Apply a specific style to a list item using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple list, which I managed to get in a line and have background image for all items. However I want to have some of the list items(List item 3) to have a different background image. Is there a way to do this without using !important? My code is Below.

**The CSS**

```
.my-list li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    background-image: url(../images/butn-bg.png);   
}
.different-bg {
        background-image: url(../images/butn-bg-1.png);
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<div class="my-list">
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li class="different-bg">List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: `.my-list li.different-bg {...}` is enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to increase the specificity of your selector:

```
.my-list li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    background-image: url(../images/butn-bg.png);   
}
.my-list li.different-bg {
        background-image: url(../images/butn-bg-1.png);
}
```

See [Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity)

Answer (score 0):

Look my example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ePTv/)

Everything is working correctly.
Try to make more common styles, and write them as a complement changes.
Add this to your css:

```
.my-list .different-bg {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/300);
}​
```

If you are interested, more details can be found here: [get specific css styles](http://www.sitepoint.com/get-specific-css-styles/)